# Стиль для IsSelected ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Задача состоит в следующем: для выделенных элементов списка должен быть изменен фон, но на данный момент со следующим кодом

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF5C7CA1"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E1E7ED"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListViewItem IsSelected="True">Item 1</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>Item 2</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>Item 3</ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Триггер для свойства `IsSelected` не работает, стили остаются системными, при чем item с указанным свойством `IsSelected` отображает только системный фон, то же самое происходит и для `IsFocused`.

Как правильно изменить триггер для изменения стиля при выделении и фокусе пункта списка?

Comment: Вы уверены, что правильно понимаете разницу между Selected и Focused?

Comment: Попробуйте `SelectionMode="Multiple"` и сообщите, что видите.

Comment: как бы я и имел в виду, чтобы изменить стиль как для isSelected, так и используя тот самый стиль при фокусе

Comment: Ааааа! Вы применяете стиль к ListViewItem? Хм. Попробуйте лучше установить `ItemContainerStyle` (это по идее то же самое, но каноничнее).

Comment: Как раз уже попробовал с ним: работают стили только для IsFocused, как для IsSelected, так и для Mouse  событий нет влияния

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361698/wpf-trigger-for-listboxitem-isselected-not-working-for-background-property) нашел ответ. Короче говоря, у `ItemContainerStyle` есть свойство `Template`, значение которого должно иметь такой вид

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
            <Setter Value="Red" Property="Background" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter Value="Green" Property="Background" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Border Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <ContentPresenter />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Ага, вот оно что. Таки шаблон по умолчанию содержит ошибку.